# matlab running a video, .txt and .mat

Tags: matlab, video, mat

I want to run a video in matlab but I got some problems while doing so. I tried to run the video while using 'load' and then 'implay'. But I got this problem. My movie file is a textfile which constains mostly of zeros, arranged diagonally.

When I load this file in matlab I get different values. Here a snippet:

```
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -5  0   0   -5.00097609500000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -10 0   0   -10.0019423800000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -15 0   0   -15.0028988550000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -20 0   0   -20.0038455200000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -25 0   0   -25.0047823750000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -30 0   0   -30.0057094200000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -35 0   0   -35.0066266550000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -40 0   0   -40.0075340800000   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   -45 0   0   -45.0084316950000   0   0   0   0   0
```

I dont know why I get a mat.file with different values and why my movie does not run. I wanted to upload the original textfile but this not possible.

When I try to run I receive following message: There is not enough memory to open 'filename' in the Editor.

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: At least there is a bit of example of how your file look like in this question. But you could have simply edited your original question : [matlab There is not enough memory to open in the editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899212/matlab-there-is-not-enough-memory-to-open-in-the-editor). As for your problem, when you drag a text file in the command window, Matlab doesn't try to "run" it but only to "open" it (in the Matlab text editor). Use `load('YourFileName.txt')` instead.

Comment: I used already load('YourFileName.txt'). The above posted snippet is the result. My problem is how I can run this file

Comment: Are you sure this file contains video data ? You say that the original file content is different that the loaded version, post a snippet of the original file as well so we can see what is changing.

Comment: 0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000  0.00000000000000

Comment: the original file is like this but bigger. It just contains zeros. In the original file they are arrangend diagonally. Something about the background: I run a simulation over time. I am interested in the results of every timestep. The movie should present the results in every time. I got this movie when my simulation ends

Comment: I count twelve `0` values ... do you not have a `-5` value soon after ? (if your file really contains only zero, then there is nothing to play)

Comment: The original really contains only zero. I get the -5 when I import this file in matlab. I cant explain why the -5 occurs.